# How to insert decimal into mysql database?

Tags: c#, mysql, decimal

I have a curious issue getting my decimal values into mysql database.

I have a table, with `amount` column marked as `decimal`

The column declaration looks something like this:

```
`amount` DECIMAL NOT NULL,
```

In my code, I'm trying to insert a row into that database using following

```
decimal amount=0.9902888269673553777395003M;

command.CommandText="insert into `mytable` (..., `amount`, ....) values (....,@amount,...)";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", amount);
```

After I execute the command, the row gets inserted into the database, but the amount is always 0, no matter what I do.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but there are cases where [`AddWithValue` picks the wrong type](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: checked for that, and no; anyway,Rahul has the right answer, I didn't define how many decimals behind comma to use so mysql defaulted on 0

Comment: You does not seems to follow proper definition for decimal type field.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Umm, you forgot to define the size of the decimal column in form of `DECIMAL(M,D)`. So your column definition should be below which means total 30 digits long number which will have maximum 15 digits after decimal point

```
`amount` DECIMAL(30,15) NOT NULL,
```